Azure Bicep - Configure additonal Defender for Cloud settings - [Containers]
Currently trying to set different Defender for Cloud specific settings through templates in Bicep.
So far Ive been able to configure a lot of settings as recourses in Bicep.
For instance, enabling Agentless Scanning for Servers:
resource serversPlan 'Microsoft.Security/pricings@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'VirtualMachines'
  dependsOn: [
    cspmPlan
  ]
  properties: {
    pricingTier: 'Standard'
    subPlan: 'P2'
  }
}

resource agentlessScanningServers 'Microsoft.Security/VmScanners@2022-03-01-preview' = {
  name: 'default'
  dependsOn: [
      serversPlan
  ]
  properties: {
    scanningMode: 'Default'
    // You can add exclusion tags to Agentless scanning for machines feature
    exclusionTags: {}
    enabled: true
  }


But I am having a hard time finding any documentation regarding enabling/disabling Defender for Cloud settings regarding Containers.
More specifically:

Agentless discovery for Kubernetes
Agentless container vulnerability assessment

Has anyone been doing any configuration for specific settings in DfC for Containers in Bicep?
And is it even possible?
Looked through the entirety of the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/ in the Security tabs. Unable to find anything regarding containers.

Configuration of defender for containers cloud is not directly possible with bicep. It can be done using portal or CLI. Is either of approaches works for you? @Fred

@Jahnavi, we want to set the settings through azure policy in Bicep. That was the whole idea :) Sad to hear it is not possible - kinda odd when so many other settings regarding dfc can be set through Bicep.

You can use this policy definition as shown in image. Also refer MSDoc. @Fred

I found the way with the resource Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters as shown here. Can you check and confirm is this the one you are looking for? @Fred

As I mentioned in the discussion, it is not exactly possible with bicep to achieve your requirement.
However, there is a profile setting called ManagedClusterSecurityProfileDefender available under the resource Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters in bicep for containers. To enable defender related profile of containers, you can use below code as detailed.
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource ws 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2023-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'newws'
}
resource clustercreate 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2024-01-02-preview' = {
  name: 'myclusterj'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Base'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {
    kubernetesVersion: '1.28.3'
    dnsPrefix: 'sdsd'
    servicePrincipalProfile: {
      clientId: '77xxxxxx45c'
      secret: 'Sgn8xxxx0cOq'
    }
    agentPoolProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'systempool'
        count: 1
        enableAutoScaling: true
        minCount: 1
        maxCount: 3
        vmSize: 'Standard_B2s'
        osType: 'Linux'
        mode: 'System'
      }
    ]
    securityProfile: {
      defender: {
        logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceId: ws.id
        securityMonitoring: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:


If you want to use an Azure policy to meet the specific requirement, refer MSDoc and assign the below policy definition.

If still the issue persists, check defender for containers doc via Portal.
